# How to set the color of page number

Tags: header-footer, color

I am  using white colored font on black page and somehow I am losing my page numbers. I suppose the page number is still in black color. So How do we set the color of page number? And while on the topic, how about color of page runners etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add all the colour information into your page style using [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr).

In the following MWE, I've defined `mypagestyle` to set the page number in `red` (using `\textcolor{red}{\thepage}`) and modified the header rule macro `\headrule`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\makeatletter
\fancypagestyle{mypagestyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyfoot[C]{\textcolor{red}{\thepage}}% Page # in middle/centre of footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.4pt}% .4pt header rule
  \def\headrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth\fi
    \color{red}\hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth \vskip-\headrulewidth}}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule
%  \def\footrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\footrulewidth\plainfootrulewidth\fi
%    \vskip-\footruleskip\vskip-\footrulewidth
%    \hrule\@width\headwidth\@height\footrulewidth\vskip\footruleskip}}
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{mypagestyle}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

The same would hold if you're interested in having a coloured footer rule. I've included the `\footrule` definition in comment, for completeness.

Comment: Thanks. How does the running title (short title) get to be treated?

Comment: @Maesumi: In the standard document class (like `article`), you could use `\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}` to place `\leftmark` (sectional heading) in the `R`ight header.

Comment: @Werner In my applied case, this answer seem to only solve the problem for **some** page-numberings, it seems (i.e. in `\documentclass{book}`, not in `\documentclass{report}`). It only works for those which are not shifted to the top of the page (sorry for not being able to use a technical term which demonstrates deeper understanding); it does e.g. not work for page numbers at the first page of a `\part{...}`.

Comment: @VincentVerheyen: That's true since `book` and `report` issue `\thispagestyle{plain}` on first pages for their `\chapter`s. This is a common scenario, and you'll have to (re)define the `plain` page style to cover those cases.

Answer (score 8):

If all you need to achieve is to change the *color* of the page numerals on a page, and if you can get by with using LaTeX's "plain" page style, the following MWE will show you how to do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor,etoolbox} % lipsum for filler text
\makeatletter % change only the display of \thepage, but not \thepage itself:
\patchcmd{\ps@plain}{\thepage}{\textcolor{red}{\thepage}}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain} % after changing a pagestyle command, it's necessary to invoke it explicitly
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

In addition to the "plain" page style, the standard LaTeX document classes also provide the "headings" and "myheadings" page styles. If you're using one of these page styles and wish to reset the color of the page numerals, you should insert the following code in your document's preamble (in addition to loading the `etoolbox` and `xcolor` packages, of course):

```
\makeatletter
% patch the "plain" page style
\patchcmd{\ps@plain}{\thepage}{\textcolor{red}{\thepage}}{}{}
% patch the "headings" page style
\if@twoside
    \patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\thepage\hfil}{\textcolor{red}{\thepage}\hfil}{}{}
    \patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\hfil\thepage}{\hfil\textcolor{red}{\thepage}}{}{}
\else
    \patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\hfil\thepage}{\hfil\textcolor{red}{\thepage}}{}{}
\fi
% patch the "myheadings" page style
\patchcmd{\ps@myheadings}{\thepage\hfil}{\textcolor{red}{\thepage}\hfil}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@myheadings}{\hfil\thepage}{\hfil\textcolor{red}{\thepage}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Then, be sure to issue either `\pagestyle{plain}`, `\pagestyle{headings}`, or `\pagestyle{myheadings}` after `\begin{document}`.